# Jquery Validation For checkbox with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to get Only one custom jquery validation message and that to in a `<div>` above element if checkbox name is array with index.

```
<div class="error">Error will show here</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="is_appraisal[0]" class="is_appraisal_f siblingcheckbox" id="is_appraisal_f">

<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="is_appraisal[1]" class="is_appraisal_s siblingcheckbox" id="is_appraisal_s">
```

I tried this but it is not working

```
   $.validator.addMethod("onechecked", function (value, elem, param) {
            if ($(".siblingcheckbox:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }, "Please select any one of the following!");

        $.validator.addClassRules("siblingcheckbox", {
            onechecked: true
   });
```

Validation is working but this gives error message below both checkbox.Any Help ?

Answer (score 2):

if you want all your jQuery Validate error messages to appear in one place you would use.http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions Find `errorPlacement` option on that page.

1)
if you want custom placement for all of your errors you can do this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo('#errordiv');
   }
});
```

2) 
If you want to specify specific locations for one or multiple error labels you can do this.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "email" )
        error.insertAfter(".some-class");
    else if  (element.attr("name") == "phone" )
        error.insertAfter(".some-other-class");
    else
        error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Edit

This bellow code  add in your validation function

```
$("#YOURFORMID").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.appendTo('.error');
            },
            success: function(label,element) {
               $('.error').html('');
            }   

});
```

NOTE:: name of checkbox is different(is_appraisal[0],is_appraisal[1]) so message will display two time.

> Also check bellow  snippet working demo for group of checkbox
>   validation with custom message set at custom place

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myform").validate({
                  rules: {
                    "is_appraisal[]": "required",

            },
            messages: {
              "is_appraisal[]": "Please select any one of the following!",
              },
              errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.appendTo('.error');
               }
            });
  });
```

```css
.error
{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="error"></div>
<form  name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="is_appraisal[]" class="is_appraisal_f siblingcheckbox" id="is_appraisal_f">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="is_appraisal[]" class="is_appraisal_s siblingcheckbox" id="is_appraisal_s">
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

Demo link https://jsfiddle.net/9q0jwxo6/1/

Comment: can you please give an example related to question.

Comment: he is using index in the name which you have removed, this changes the meaning of question.

Comment: Yes i removed the index  from name no need to add index in name it's default add the index

Comment: Why down vote above code is working and remove index code is for demo

Comment: @AnkurBhadania - i am using index because i am check isset in server side and  error message is not disappearing even after selection.

Comment: @ShakunChaudhary you need to add success: method in validate check edit ans

Answer (score 1):

Jquery validation library generates a label for each invalid html element like:

```
<label id="email_id-error" class="error" for="email_id">Please enter your Email.</label>
```

Just copy this label from html dom and remove its error message and put it on place where you want the error message. Now the error message placement is where this label is.